# How to apply group by on nested document in MongoDB using MongoTemplate?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb, mongotemplate

```
db.students.aggregate([
  { $unwind: "$details" },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        sid: "$details.student._id",
        statuscode: "$details.studentStatus.statusCode"
      },
      total: { $sum: 1 }
    }
  }
]);
```

The query is working fine and need to convert into *mongo template*.

Sample document:

```
{
        "_id" : 59,
        "details" : [
                {
                        "student" : {
                                "_id" : "5d3145a8523a2e602e5e0200"
                        },
                        "studentStatus" : {
                                "statusCode" : 1
                        }
                }
        ]
}
```

Comment: Please do provide a sample document as JSON in the post.

Comment: {
  "_id": 59,
  "details": [
    {
      "student": {
        "_id": "5d3145a8523a2e602e5e0200",  
      },
      "studentStatus": {
        "statusCode": 1
      }, 
    }
  ]
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Spring Data `MongoTemplate` code for the given aggregation is as follows.

Note that I have added a *project* stage before the *group*. This *project* is required; if the nested fields ("details.student._id" and "details.studentStatus.statusCode") are used directly within the *group* stage there are errors `"FieldPath field names may not contain '.'."` and could not be resolved (and this only happens when you use more than one field in the grouping).

The result is same as that of the aggregation you have provided. I have used the latest of Spring and MongoDB drivers with Java 8.

```
MongoOperations mongoOps = new MongoTemplate(MongoClients.create(), "spr_test");

Aggregation agg = newAggregation(
                                unwind("details"),    
                                project("_id")
                                    .and("details.student._id").as("sid")
                                    .and("details.studentStatus.statusCode").as("statuscode"),
                                group("sid", "statuscode")
                                    .count().as("total")
);

AggregationResults<Document> aggResults = mongoOps.aggregate(agg, "students", Document.class);
aggResults.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: But if I want the Aggregation.ROOT (whole object), project does not allow me to get that

Comment: In such a case use `$addFields` instead of the `$project` - both are projection stages for different purposes. The _addFields_ includes all fields, by default.