# How to do aggregation in java using Mongo Template

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, aggregation-framework, mongotemplate

I'm new to MongoDB!

Can anyone please help me on **how to write java code to convert the below mongo aggregation query**?
Currently, I'm writing this in a spring boot application having "spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb" as a dependency. I'm thinking to use Mongo Template to fetch grouped docs using the below Query.

```
db.getCollection('test').aggregate([  
{
    $group: {
        _id: { name: "$name", zip: "$recipients.0.address.postalcode" },
        groupedDocs: { $addToSet: "$$ROOT" }
    }
}
]);
```

Comment: Here is post with grouping aggregation using `MongoTemplate`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59639379/how-to-apply-group-by-on-nested-document-in-mongodb-using-mongotemplate/59657290#59657290

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the MongoTemplate is the right idea. You need to create your aggregation first like this:

```
var aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(
    Aggregation.group(Fields.from(
            Fields.field("name"),
            Fields.field("zip", "recipients.0.address.postalcode")
        )
    ).addToSet("$$ROOT")
);
```

Of course you could use static imports to make it more concise, I wrote it like this so you can find the classes better. I am not sure about the $$ROOT reference, you might have to look that up. With this, you can call the MongoTemplate:

```
return mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, "Test", Test.class);
```

Comment: Thanks @Sebastian, I'll try this solution!